# ZAP API scan error using zap-api-scan.py

Tags: continuous-integration, zap, openapi

In my CI setup I use the following command:

```
docker run -v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly \
              zap-api-scan.py -t openapi.json -f openapi -c .zap-baseline.conf -d
```

It should scan according to the `openapi.json` swagger/openapi definition file. As far as I can see from the python code. But it seems that it can't find any URL to scan from the openapi definition. As seen below.

```
$ docker run -v /etc/hosts:/etc/hosts -v $(pwd):/zap/wrk:rw -t owasp/zap2docker-weekly zap-api-scan.py -t openapi.json -f openapi -c .zap-baseline.conf -r zap-baseline-scan-report.html -x zap-baseline-scan-report.xml -w zap-baseline-scan-report.md -d
2017-11-22 16:21:49,963 Using port: 39381

2017-11-22 16:21:49,963 Starting ZAP

_XSERVTransmkdir: ERROR: euid != 0,directory /tmp/.X11-unix will not be created.

Nov 22, 2017 4:21:57 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run

INFO: Created user preferences directory.

2017-11-22 16:22:01,255 ZAP Version D-2017-11-20

2017-11-22 16:22:01,255 Took 11 seconds

2017-11-22 16:22:01,280 Import OpenAPI File openapi.json

2017-11-22 16:22:01,707 Failed to import any URLs

2017-11-22 16:22:01,708 Number of Imported URLs: 0

2017-11-22 16:22:01,708 Import warnings: []
```

I get some hard exceptions that seem to terminate the scan at the end of the same output:

```
8360 [ZAP-daemon] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.DaemonBootstrap  - ZAP is now listening on 0.0.0.0:39381

9502 [ZAP-Import-OpenAPI-1] WARN org.zaproxy.zap.extension.openapi.ExtensionOpenApi  - 

java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.openapi.generators.PathGenerator.generateFullPath(PathGenerator.java:51)

    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.openapi.converter.swagger.RequestModelConverter.generatePath(RequestModelConverter.java:63)

    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.openapi.converter.swagger.RequestModelConverter.convert(RequestModelConverter.java:48)

    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.openapi.converter.swagger.SwaggerConverter.convertToRequest(SwaggerConverter.java:75)

    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.openapi.converter.swagger.SwaggerConverter.getRequestModels(SwaggerConverter.java:69)

    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.openapi.ExtensionOpenApi$3.run(ExtensionOpenApi.java:212)

9691 [ZAP-ProxyThread-9] WARN org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API  - Bad request to API endpoint [/JSON/ascan/action/scan/] from [127.0.0.1]:

Provided parameter has illegal or unrecognized value (illegal_parameter) : url

    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascan.ActiveScanAPI.scanURL(ActiveScanAPI.java:763)

    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascan.ActiveScanAPI.handleApiAction(ActiveScanAPI.java:293)

    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API.handleApiRequest(API.java:431)

    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.processHttp(ProxyThread.java:456)

    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.run(ProxyThread.java:317)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

14705 [ZAP-ProxyThread-10] WARN org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API  - Bad request to API endpoint [/JSON/ascan/view/status/] from [127.0.0.1]:

Does Not Exist (does_not_exist) : scanId

    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascan.ActiveScanAPI.getActiveScan(ActiveScanAPI.java:654)

    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.ascan.ActiveScanAPI.handleApiView(ActiveScanAPI.java:827)

    at org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API.handleApiRequest(API.java:467)

    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.processHttp(ProxyThread.java:456)

    at org.parosproxy.paros.core.proxy.ProxyThread.run(ProxyThread.java:317)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

My **`openapi.json`** definition file looks like this:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "BSS-API",
        "description": "Client BSS API",
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "host": "api.client.tst",
    "basePath": "/",
    "schemes": [
        "https"
    ],
    "consumes": [
        "application/json",
        "application/javascript"
    ],
    "produces": [
        "application/json",
        "application/javascript"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/availability/username_password_pair/{username}/{password}": {
            "get": {
                "summary": "Returns username password pair availability information",
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Availability information"
                    },
                    "default": {
                        "description": "an \"unexpected\" error"
                    }
                }
            },
            "parameters": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#/securityDefinitions/api_key"
                },
                {
                    "name": "username",
                    "in": "path",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "password",
                    "in": "path",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "definitions": {},
    "securityDefinitions": {
        "api_key": {
            "type": "apiKey",
            "name": "HTTP-apikey",
            "in": "header"
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect ZAP to at least find the URL `https://api.client.tst/availability/username_password_pair/{username}/{password}` from the openapi definition file.

FYI: The `api.client.tst` domain it's IP is defined in my `/etc/hosts` file. And it's my experience that ZAP doesn't require any SSL certificate to be validated (like any browser would normally do) for the https scheme.

My **question** is twofold:

1. What openapi/swagger versions are supported by the zap-api-scan.py script?
2. Could it be that I'm doing something wrong in my swagger 2.0 definition file (so ZAP can't find my URL from it)?

---

**Edit:** 
I currently filed a bug report over here: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/4072

Also it seems that [openapi/swagger 2.0 should currently be supported](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zaproxy-users/35X07D8sTQo/_O-lRahJAgAJ).

Comment: Could you try using the [stable](https://hub.docker.com/r/owasp/zap2docker-stable/) image? If it does not reproduce there (I saw some errors in the logs), I would suggest opening an issue in Zap repo.

Comment: It seems `zap-api-scan.py` is not available on the stable branch yet. Because I get the `"exec: \"zap-api-scan.py\": executable file not found in $PATH".` This [wiki page](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ZAP-API-Scan) seems to confirm that, saying *"The ZAP API scan is a script that is available in the ZAP Live and Weekly Docker images"*.

Comment: You're right. I thought it wasn't part only of the bare, forgot about the stable.

Comment: So would you suggest to create an issue in the zaproxy/zaproxy github repo and refer to this page?

Comment: I am not sure this is a Zap error: `Bad request to API endpoint [/JSON/ascan/action/scan/] from [127.0.0.1]:

Provided parameter has illegal or unrecognized value (illegal_parameter) : url
`. That why I suggested trying with another image. You can try to look at the code, to understand the error. Or ask also in [Zap's user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/zaproxy-users)

Comment: I tried with the live image which gives me that error you mention as well. But I get the feeling that it might have something to do with the first part of the output being:  

    `2017-11-23 08:51:07,818 Import OpenAPI File openapi.json`  
    `2017-11-23 08:51:08,209 Failed to import any URLs`  
    `2017-11-23 08:51:08,209 Number of Imported URLs: 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159652/discussion-between-tommy-bravo-and-omer-levi-hevroni).